# pytest monkeypatch.setattr() inside of test class method

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test class with few test methods and I want to patch some app classes and methods from the test methods. 
In pytest docs I found [an example](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html#simple-example-monkeypatching-functions) of how to use monkeypatch module for tests. It that example all tests are just functions, not testclass methods.

But I have a class with test methods:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
   def setUp():
     pass

   def test_classmethod(self, monkeypatch):
     # here I want to use monkeypatch.setattr()
     pass
```

And just passing `monkeypatch` as method param is obviously doesn't work. So looks like py.test magic doesn't work this way.

So the question is simple and maybe stupid: how can I use  `monkeypatch.setattr()` for pytest inside from the test class method?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It [can't work](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html) in this form

> While pytest supports receiving fixtures via test function arguments
>   for non-unittest test methods, unittest.TestCase methods cannot
>   directly receive fixture function arguments as implementing that is
>   likely to inflict on the ability to run general unittest.TestCase test
>   suites.

You might create `monkeypatch` directly

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch

class MyTest(TestCase):
   def setUp():
     self.monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()

   def test_classmethod(self):
     self.monkeypatch.setattr ...
     ...
```

or create own fixture, which will add `monkeypatch` to your class, and use `@pytest.mark.usefixtures`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def monkeypatch_for_class(request):
    request.cls.monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("monkeypatch_for_class")
class MyTest(TestCase):
   def setUp():
     pass

   def test_classmethod(self):
     self.monkeypatch.setattr ...
     ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't `setUp()` function have a `self` argument?

Comment: Hi, wonderful answer. Why in import statement there is underscore before pytest? `from _pytest`

Comment: I also have to add tearDown() with self.monkeypatch.undo()

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem.
This works perfectly

```py
import unittest
import pandas as pd
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
from src.geipan_data import loadLongitudeLatitudeDateTestimony

class TestGeipanData(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()

    def test_loadLongitudeLatitudeDateTestimony(self):

        def read_csv(*args, **kwargs):
            return pd.DataFrame({
                'obs_date_heure': ['2010-05-21', '1926-05-21'],
                'obs_1_lon': [45.123, 78.4564],
                'obs_1_lat': [32.123, 98.4564],
            })

        self.monkeypatch.setattr(pd, 'read_csv', read_csv)

        df = loadLongitudeLatitudeDateTestimony()

        self.assertListEqual(
            df.columns.values.tolist(),
            ['obs_date_heure', 'obs_1_lon', 'obs_1_lat']
        )
```

In this example I do mock the pd.read_csv method with monkey patch and I uses asserListEqual that extends from unittest.TestCase